# Android: Uri throws NoSuchFieldException

Tags: java, android

With this method below, I play the videos on the list.

```
videoItem.setVideoPath(filePaths.get(position));
videoItem.setClickable(true);
videoItem.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        player.playVideo(videoItem);
        return true;
    }
});
```

The `videoItem` variable is an instance of the `VideoView` class, and the `player` variable and its method is from the custom `VideoPlayer` class.

Here is the `VideoPlayer` class.

```
public class VideoPlayer {
    private Context context;
    private Uri uri;
    private boolean isVideoPlaying = false;

    public VideoPlayer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void getVideoUri(VideoView video) {
        try {
            Field field = VideoView.class.getDeclaredField("uri");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            uri = (Uri) field.get(video);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception caught: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void playVideo(VideoView video) {
        getVideoUri(video);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(context);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(video);
        video.setMediaController(mediaController);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.start();
        isVideoPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

When I tap the video views, it starts to play. That's not a problem. But at the same time the toast message that is thrown when an exception is caught is also shown. Why is the exception happening in the code?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Can you add the Exception Stack Trace in your question ? We can't help you much without it =)

Comment: @Kapcash It says `Exception caught: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: uri`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error says `"uri"` is not a field of VideoView class, check VideoView class and correct the name of the field you are trying to access.

Comment: The field name is "mUri" in the version I looked at.